# WPF Synchronization to multiple computers

Tags: wpf, synchronization

I'm trying to find out if anyone has managed to get WPF to synchronize video across multiple computers.

I'm trying to determine if this is possible?

Same as this question here, [Is it possible to synchronize videos across multiple computers using WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914958/is-it-possible-to-synchronize-videos-across-multiple-computers-using-wpf). There appeared to be potential for MPF Mediakit to do it, but never really heard how this worked out.

I need to develop an application that supports video walls. It would be hugely beneficial if this could be achieved between individual computers connected to individual monitors rather than having a bulky computer with uber expensive multi-head graphics card. I've also read that WPF looses it's ability to leverage hardware acceleration when an application spans multiple monitors.

I've seen something for Linux that can do it, but I'm not going down that path...

Anyone interested in developing something for me (paid)?

Ben

Comment: It would seem like you have your starting point already.  If you are looking for someone to actually do the work for you, this isn't the place for that.  If you have some code that you just can't get to work, we can look it over and give you a hand.  My suggestion would be to go to www.vworker.com with your issue and pay someone to do this work for you.